# Crime Statistics on Abductions by Gender

Tags: data-request, usa

I am looking for crime statistics (datasets) on attempted and actual abductions in the United States by gender. I am interested in seeing the statistical differences by gender.

Comment: The problem with this dataset is that it would be incredibly difficult for anyone to collect data on. I think the better search is to look for missing persons reports data.

Comment: Another option is to start with a local area, which may have local-specific data.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that you'd have to know about all of the attempted abduction attempts ... and the successful ones, which [might not be known until years later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariel_Castro_kidnappings).

Comment: @Kotebiya Maybe someone with a statistics background could create a model to correlate the missing-persons data with a known kidnapping. As in, take the name, gender, race, and location of everyone who was reported missing, note whether there were suspicious circumstances involved, then see if that person was ever found and if any arrests were made in connection with that person's case. Should be easy to then use that data to estimate the total number of people who have been abducted.

Answer (score 3):

This publication has a lot detailed statistics, including breakdown by state/city on abduction/kidnappings. But I did not see a breakdown by gender.

http://www.insideprison.com/Crime_Rates_Detailed_splash.asp?crime=100&crimeName=Kidnaping/Abduction

The FBI UCR tables do have a breakdown of arrests by gender and category, though they do not breakout Kidnapping/Abductions in this set of tables. I suspect they are merged into other categories. You may need to do some researching on the site.

http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/crime-in-the-u.s/2013/crime-in-the-u.s.-2013/persons-arrested/persons-arrested