# Where can I find adult abduction victim statistics for the United States?

Tags: crime

Usually, I can go to the National Crime Victimization Survey's Website for victimization data, but adult abductions are so rare that the Survey doesn't have a category for them.

Comment: Sounds like a familiar question :)  http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4172/1511